# Is it safe to override hashCode() and equals() on Mongo entity class

Tags: java, mongodb

Can you please help me?

I have Mongo entity which contains `_id` self generated by Mongo.

I would like to have easier mechanism of comparing these entities by excluding this `_id` from comparison.

I’m using Lombok, so added annotation

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude=“_id”)
```

I did not find any influence of this on create/save/query these items from Mongo, but maybe I miss something

Is it OK to exclude `_id` from `equals()` and `hashCode()`? Does it take influence on how they will be saved by Mongo?
(I have another buisiness key on that entity but I need `_id` self generated anyway)

Comment: I think your application requirement should drive how you define your `equals` override. How are two objects considered equal (or not equal)? What properties determine the equality of two objects? See Javadocs on [Object#equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/).

Comment: Yes, I know this.
I asked about how Mongo will drive entities with equals/hashcode overriden. Maybe it uses them for comparing entities provided with one it has in storage; maybe it saves them right like hashmap does, so it needs to be very careful - in a meaning that data will be saved in Mongo using not performant structure. I did not investigate code, decided to ask.